# The return type 'int' isn't a 'int', as defined by anonymous closure

Tags: dart

I defined a function as a type named "TestDelegate" in dart, and I used it like below:

```dart
typedef TestDelegate = T Function<T>();
TestDelegate delegate = <int>(){
  return 1;  <== error line
};
```

It generated a error:

> The return type 'int' isn't a 'int', as defined by anonymous closure.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: For the record: Your function value is a generic function, with a type parameter named `<int>`. It is as if you wrote `<X>() { return 1; }` with an expected type of `T Function<T>()`. The literal `1` has type `int` (the type from `dart:core`) which is not of type `int` (the type variable you just introduced).

Comment: @lrn, thank you for the explanation!  But what in the world does the error message actually mean?  Why is a closure mentioned?

Comment: The second `int` mentioned is the `<int>(){...}` type parameter of the anonymous closure. The context type means that the `<int>(){...}` function (let's write it as `<X>() { ... }` instead, because the `int` here is just a variable name) is inferred to have the `X Function<X>()`. Then it complains because `1` is of type `int` and not assignable to `X`. Then everything gets confused because the type variable isn't called `X`, but `int`. If it had been `X`, then it would have said "`The return type 'int' isn't a 'X', as defined by anonymous closure.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the generic on TestDelegate

```dart
typedef TestDelegate<T> = T Function();

void main() {
  print('RESULT: ${_delegate()}');
}

TestDelegate<int> _delegate = () {
  return 1;
};
```